# Speed up for NDSolveValue containing a coefficient of interpolate function

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, parallelization

Could you give me some advice to speed up this code? I think especially NDSolveValue takes a lot of time.

For j=1, it the NDSolveValue seems to be fast. But for j=2, I use the result of previous NDSolveValue(interpolate function) as a coefficient for another NDSolveValue, which seems takes lots of time.

I am running on a server of 24 cores, but I am not sure how I can take the advantage of that to speed up.

```
u = 2;
c = 3000;
it = 3;
Array[h, {u, c}];
Do[Do[h[i, k] = 0, {i, u}], {k, c}];
F[x_] := Sin[x];
AA[x_] := 1/(x^2 + 1);
w[x_] := F[x] + AA[x];
v[x_] := Sum[w[x + i*2 Pi], {i, -it, it}];

Do[n = 1;
  If[j == 1,
   While[n <= c, 
     h[j, n] = 
      NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == Cos[y[x]], y'[0] == 0, y[0] == n}, 
       y, {x, 0, 1}, 
       "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
           "TimeConstraint" -> Infinity}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]; n++];,
   While[n <= c, h[j, n] = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == Cos[y[x]]
          + Sum[v[h[j - 1, n][x] - h[j - 1, i][x]], {i, 1, c}], 
        y'[0] == 0, y[0] == n}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
       "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
           "TimeConstraint" -> Infinity}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3.];
     n++];];, {j, u}];
```

I am not sure how I can accommodate parallelize for the NDSolveValue. I tried to use Compile instead of functions, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with interpolate function.

Comment: Questions with so much code tend not to attract much attention.  Can you capture the essence of your problem with a shorter example?

Comment: I revised the previous code to a simpler one to address the essence only.

Answer (score 1):

First setting a more reasonable amount of DEs to solve for my laptop,

```
c = 50;
```

I find the OP's code takes `4.45876` seconds to run.

The dependence of `h[j, n]` on previous solutions limits what can be parallelized.  For each `j`, the following parallelizes the solutions for all `n`.  Since you don't want the subkernels calling back to the main kernel to set the value of `h[j, n]`, I changed the loop to `ParallelTable` and stored the list of solutions in `hh[j]`.  The solution `h[j, n]` will then correspond to `hh[j][[n]]`.  (I don't know if the `Method` setting is necessary for high values of `c`; it was unnecessary for the following.)

It's 2.5 times faster for `c = 50` on my 4/8-core i7 laptop.  For each `j`, the new definition of `hh` have to be distributed to each subkernel, which probably accounts for some of the limitations in gain of speed.

```
Clear[hh];
Do[
   If[j == 1,
     hh[j] = ParallelTable[
       NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == Cos[y[x]], y'[0] == 0, y[0] == n}, 
        y, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 3],
       {n, c}],
     hh[j] = ParallelTable[
       NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == 
          Cos[y[x]] + Sum[v[hh[j - 1][[n]][x] - hh[j - 1][[i]][x]], {i, 1, c}], 
         y'[0] == 0, y[0] == n}, y, {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 3.],
       {n, c}]
     ];,
   {j, u}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.71541, Null}  *)
```

Spot check a value with OP's code:

```
h[1, 23][0.62]
hh[1][[23]][0.62]
%% - %
(*
  22.8948
  22.8948
  0.
*)
```

Check another solution over the domain (the difference is zero at all sampling points):

```
Plot[h[2, 23][x] - hh[2][[23]][x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]